# i am trying to select data from table & put that data in table format on webpage by using Listview but i got error

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to get data from my database/table & print that data into a number of textfield s. All the textfields are in listview but it gives an following error:

> Error: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.cerebrum.pages.AdminViewUser()

please check my code:

```
 public class AdminViewUser extends Home
   {
        Users UserModel=new Users();
List<Users> listCal = new ArrayList<Users>();
public AdminViewUser()
{
    super();
    add(new AdminViewUserForm());
}

public class AdminViewUserForm extends Form
{
    public AdminViewUserForm()
    {
    super("AdminViewUserForm");

    /*final WebMarkupContainer webMarkupContainer = new   WebMarkupContainer("webMarkupContainer");
    add(webMarkupContainer);
    webMarkupContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);*/

     ListView listViewCal = new ListView("listViewCal", listCal) 
     {
         protected void populateItem(ListItem item) 
            {
    CheckBox chkBoxSelect=new CheckBox("chkBoxSelect");
    add(chkBoxSelect);

    TextField first_name=new TextField("txtFname");
    add(first_name);

    TextField middle_name=new TextField("txtMname");
    add(middle_name);

    TextField last_name=new TextField("txtLname");
    add(last_name);

    TextField dateOfBirth=new TextField("txtDOB");
    add(dateOfBirth);

    TextField emailid=new TextField("txtEmail");
    add(emailid);

    TextField mobileno=new TextField("txtMobileNo");
    add(mobileno);

    TextField user_name=new TextField("txtUserName");
    add(user_name);

    TextField password=new TextField("txtPassword");
    add(password);
     }
};
     listViewCal.setOutputMarkupId(true);
     add(listViewCal);
        //webMarkupContainer.add(listViewCal);

        List lstUsers=UsersHome.getUserInfo();
        for(Iterator iterator=lstUsers.iterator();iterator.hasNext();)
        {
            Object[] obj=(Object[])iterator.next();
            System.out.println(obj[8].toString()+"***************");
            listCal.add(new Users(obj[8].toString(),obj[9].toString(),obj[10].toString(),obj[18].toString(),obj[14].toString(),obj[12].toString(),obj[6].toString(),obj[7].toString()));

        }

    }




}
}
```

Comment: More like a debug-it-for-me-question

Comment: Have a look at the whole stack trace to see what's really causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code. First of, check the exception. The real problem is further down. Wicket shows the "Error: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.cerebrum.pages.AdminViewUser()" because there was an exception in that constructor. My guess it that you will find a NullPointerException.

Than, you don't provide models for your form components (CheckBoxes, Textfields). Wicket would not know how to read and set values from your User objects. One way is to set a CompoundPropertyModel in the populateItem().

You construct the User from a bunch of strings, but later access members for Checkboxes. Checkboxes require a boolean Model.

Not sure how you read the User objects. But the casting from a Object[] seems just to easy to break...